# This is a question about proving that a limit is positive. I would like to know how to approach the problem.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $c$ is an accumulation point of $D$.  Show that, if $f(x) \geq 0$, for all $x \in D$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) \geq 0$.

My first thought was that $c \in D$. If that were the case then of course $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) \geq 0$. But then I realized that it might not be an element of D. I don't know what to do now. I know the definition for how to prove a limit, but I don't know how to apply it to this case, especially because the answer is an inequality instead of a specific number.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contradiction: If the limit is less than zero, every neighborhood around $c$ has some $x$ with $x\neq c$, $f(x)<0$. One such $x$ is enough to provide a contradiction.